# Why is the order of the fields in datagridview wrong? (Reading file in datagridview)

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here is my primary abstract class Citizen containing essential attributes for the derived classes:

```
abstract class Citizen
{
    public string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private int age;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
        }
    }
    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return lastname;
        }
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
        }
    }
    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my derived class warrior:

```
class Warrior : Citizen
{
    string weapon;
    double height;
    double weight;

    public string Weapon
    {
        get
        {
            return weapon;
        }
        set
        {
            weapon = value;
        }
    }
    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }
        set
        {
            height = value;
        }
    }
    public double Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return height;
        }
        set
        {
            height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Program is rying to read the file and write it into the datagrid:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    List<Warrior> values = new List<Warrior>(); 
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(0);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        int N = 0;
        try
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 
        }
        catch { MessageBox.Show("You have not chosen any files."); }

        try
        {
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName,Encoding.Default); 
            do
            {
                read.ReadLine();
                N++;
            }
            while (!read.EndOfStream);

            Warrior[] warrior = new Warrior[N];
            string[] temp; 
            read = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.Default);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                temp = read.ReadLine().Split(' '); 
                warrior[i] = new Warrior(); 
                warrior[i].Surname = temp[0];
                warrior[i].Name = temp[1];
                warrior[i].Year = int.Parse(temp[2]);
                warrior[i].Weapon = temp[3];
                values.Add(warrior[i]); 
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The file is either filled wrongly or corrupted.");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        bindingSource1.DataSource = values; 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1; 
        this.Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Size.Width + 10, this.Size.Height);
    }
```

And when I launch the program I get this:
[image]
So why have I got additional fields like weapon, height etc coming first? How to make it display name,surname and age first?

Comment: Looks like it's defaulting to the order of properties in the class definition itself.  Where do you define any other specific order?  Where do you define the columns of your data grid?  No column order is guaranteed unless you explicitly define it.  Sounds like you need to check the design specifications for the `dataGridView1` control.

Comment: So, adding something like this:
DataGridView1.Columns["Name"].DisplayIndex = 0;
should solve the problem?

Comment: @NazarBeiar, yes. Adding `....DisplayIndex = ?` should solve the problem.

Comment: You could also declare the columns yourself instead of letting it autogenerate. Have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using DisplayIndex does the job when I display it onto the datagridview. But when I save it,the order is messed up again, because the actual indexes are left unchanged. How to solve it?